# how do i map over some vectors to render multiple outputs in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, purrr

To avoid multiple lines with basically the same code, i want to map over multiple (two in this case) vectors to render multiple (two in this case) plots with my custom plot function.
What am i missing with my code?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
if (interactive()) {
  options(device.ask.default = FALSE)
  
  ui = fluidPage(
  plotOutput(outputId = "plotOne"),
  plotOutput(outputId = "plotTwo"))

server = function(input, output, session){

  ###define dataset filter vector
  vars = c("virginica", "setosa")
  
  ###define outputId vector
  outputIds = c("plotOne", "plotTwo")
  
  ###define plotting function
  plot_function = function(vars, outputIds){
    
    output$outputIds = renderPlot({
      iris %>%
        filter(Species == vars) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_histogram()
    })
  }
  
  map2(.x = vars, .y = outputIds, .f = plot_function)

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you’re assigning to `output$outputIds`, not to `output$plotOne` or `output$plotTwo`. You need to use `output[[outputIds]]` instead of `$` subsetting. The latter only works with hard-coded names, not with variables.

Comment: And for another `filter(Species %in% vars)` since `vars` is also a vector.

Comment: thanks both! so is this what they call `Tidy evaluation`?

Comment: @pseudospin No, the naming is just confusing; but inside the function, `vars` contains a single value.

Comment: @werN No, this has (almost) nothing to do with tidy evaluation. `foo$bar` is *non-standard evaluation*; but tidy evaluation is a special form of non-standard evaluation. `filter` and `aes` use it, but `$` doesn’t.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating multiple ggplot's why not use facets here?

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui = fluidPage(
  plotOutput(outputId = "plot"),
)

server = function(input, output, session){
  
  ###define dataset filter vector
  vars = c("virginica", "setosa")
  
    
    output$plot = renderPlot({
      iris %>%
        filter(Species %in% vars) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length)) +
        geom_histogram() + 
        facet_wrap(~Species)
    })
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I was more concerned with rendering multiple outputs with map in a more generall way regardless of the type of output. But thanks for ur answer!